Race condition between Activity.onStart() and ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected
I'm making a system service, and also a sdk library for application using. I'm trying to provide a one-call method for binding service so that application doesn't need to take too much attention on this. This is how I plan to do in sdk library.
public class TestServiceManager {

    private static final String BINDER_PKG = "testservicemanager";
    private static final String BINDER_CLASS = "testservicemanager.TestServiceManager";
    private ITestService mBinder = null;
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = null;

    public TestServiceManager(Context context) {
        doBindService(context);
    }

    // this API is exposed through jar for apps to use
    public synchronized String getInformation() {
        String info;
        try {
            if (mBinder != null) {
                info = mBinder.getInformation();
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "mBinder is null!!");
            }

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "API call failed!!");
        }
        return info;
    }

    private synchronized void doBindService(Context context) {
        mConnection =
            new ServiceConnection() {
                public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                    mBinder = ITestService.Stub.asInterface(service);
                }

                public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
                    mBinder = null;
                }
            };

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(BINDER_PKG, BINDER_CLASS));
        if (false == context.bindServiceAsUser(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE, UserHandle.SYSTEM)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doBindService failed!");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "doBindService success!");
        }
    }
}


And I have this sample app to illustrate sdk library usage.
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int result = 0;
    private TestServiceManager mManager = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mManager = new TestServiceManager(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mManager.getInformation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i(TAG, "in onDestroy");
    }
}

Now I encounter a race condition problem between onStart() and onServiceConnected(). onServiceConnected() is always called after onStart(), so when calling getInformation() in onStart(), mBinder is always null. So I'm trying to get help here.
I hope to keep it simple for application to bind the service, also the service needs to run in a single instance. Here are some methods I tried.

Create a separate thread with separate looper, and call bindServiceAsUser() in this thread. But onServiceConnected() is still called on main thread.
Modify AndroidManifest.xml, added “android:process” to let activities running in separate processes. But all activities still had same main thread and same looper.
Use reflect to call hidden function bindServiceAsUser(), which accepts Handler as parameter. But NoSuchMethodException happens.
Call bindService() to bind service, so that I can specify an Executor for onServiceConnected. But several processes of my service are created under different uid.

